# Reactor Java unit test what is the order of return values from a mocked dependency

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mono, project-reactor

I am a beginner at Reactive Java.  I am trying to understand why a simple unit test fails when a mock dependency is setup to return two different values.  This dependency is called twice in the main class that is being tested.

There is a reason I am using `flatmap` and `then` as I want the first Mono to complete before the second one.  An example of this could be writing data into database and then reading it from the database in the same chain.

Here is the main class that is being tested:

```
package my.service;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class ToBeTested {

    private final ToBeMocked toBeMocked;

    public ToBeTested(ToBeMocked toBeMocked) {
        this.toBeMocked = toBeMocked;
    }


    public Mono<String> toBeTested() {
        return Mono.just("any")
                .flatMap(unused -> toBeMocked.toBeMocked())
                .then(toBeMocked.toBeMocked());
    }
}
```

Here is the dependency class:

```
package my.service;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class ToBeMocked {

    public Mono<String> toBeMocked() {
        return Mono.just("unused string");
    }
}
```

And here is the JUnit test:

```
package my.service;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks;

class ToBeTestedTest {

    @Mock
    private ToBeMocked toBeMocked;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testTheOrderOfMockReturnValues() {
        when(toBeMocked.toBeMocked())
                .thenReturn(Mono.just("1"))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just("2"));

        ToBeTested toBeTested = new ToBeTested(toBeMocked);

        StepVerifier.create(toBeTested.toBeTested())
                .expectNext("2")
                .verifyComplete();
    }

}
```

This test fails and the error is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(2)" failed (expected value: 2; actual value: 1)
```

When logging reactive execution:

```
Test worker] reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2                : onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.ThenIgnoreMain)
Test worker] reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2                : request(unbounded)
Test worker] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
Test worker] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | request(unbounded)
Test worker] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onNext(2)
Test worker] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.1                   : | onComplete()
Test worker] reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2                : onNext(1)
Test worker] reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2                : cancel()
Test worker] reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2                : onComplete()
```

If I setup mock return values in the reverse order, the test passes.  Why?

```
when(toBeMocked.toBeMocked())
                .thenReturn(Mono.just("2"))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just("1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sources like `Mono.just("1")` are eager. In your case, this means that `.then(toBeMocked.toBeMocked())` is immediately invoked emitting `"1"` and then `.flatMap(unused -> toBeMocked.toBeMocked())` emits `"2"`.

To solve this, you can use the `defer` operator in order to make this source lazy:

```
.then(Mono.defer(()-> toBeMocked.toBeMocked()))
```

In this way, the content of the lambda is evaluated each time there is a subscriber.